# See the requests executed by pagespeed

Tags: parsing, pagespeed

When [testing my page using pagespeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-edumaps-ar/mjsnla8r3w?form_factor=desktop), it shows an error message related to a failed request in the flow:
[screenshot with the app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6aC4.jpg)
The message itself is generated by the app, when it couldn't load some resources.

The pseudo code that gets that content has a method `fetchFacts` that does fetch using GET. And, if it fails, calls itself again and does a second request to an alternate url to get the info.

```
async fetchFacts(url) {
  await fetch(url ...).then((response) => {...}).then((data) => {...}).catch((error) => { fetchFacts(alternate_url);});
}
```

When looking at my app access logs, I see that the fetch to the first URL returns an HTTP code 200, but then it does also a call to alternate_url, that fails with an HTTP code 499 (client closed connection in nginx). And - I assume - the error shown is related to this 2nd invoke.

If testing the app by myself, the 2nd invoke is not executed.

I'd assume that the PageSpeed parser does some specific action to execute that 2nd invoke, but I don't know where to get more details to understand it, and eventually prevent that behavior.

Can I read that logic somewhere? Or debug the process somehow?